# Java - getMethod null check

Tags: java

I have a class as below, before I set the data I need to check whether `getValue()` is present and it's value is empty.

```
public class Money {
{
    private String value;
    private String currency;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
   }
}

//JSON is like this
  "money": {
    "currency": "USD",
    "value": ""
}
```

I want to check whether this getValue() is present or not like `obj.getMoney().getValue() != null`,
 and then I need to check it's value is empty... `obj.getMoney().getValue().equals("")` but it fails on this condition `obj.getMoney().getValue() != null` as null.

Comment: How does it "fail"? Is there an exception, error, or unexpected behavior? Please show the code that produces the problem and the full stack trace of any exceptions or errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the following check fails

```
if (obj.getMoney().getValue() != null) { ... }
```

then it implies that the money object itself is `null`.  In this case, you can slightly modify your `if` condition to check for this:

```
if (obj.getMoney() != null && obj.getMoney().getValue() != null) { ... }
```

Comment: (obj.getMoney() != null && obj.getMoney().getValue() != null)  2nd condition was failing as the getValue is null

Comment: @SaraSara No, if `getValue()` returns `null` then your current check would _not_ fail.

Answer (score 0):

obj.getMoney().getValue() will give you null pointer exception. You should check for null object before using . after it. Example code:

Below code looks huge but it's actually readable and it will be optimized by compiler.

```
if(obj != null){
    Money money = obj.getMoney();
    if(money != null) {
        String value = money.getValue();
        //Add you logic here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting null point exception. You are facing this exception because obj.getMoney() is already null. Since you are trying to get a null object's value, so you are getting this exception. Correct code will be

```
if ((obj.getMoney() != null) && (obj.getMoney().getValue().trim().length() > 0)) { 
    // Execute your code here
}
```

Comment: if ((obj.getMoney() != null) && (obj.getMoney().getValue() != null)) 2nd condition is false because its value of getValue().

Comment: @SaraSara I have edited code. Hope it will works fine. First you need to trim the value. Trim remove all whitespace. Then check your values length. If you have any value then its length definitely will be greater then 0.

Answer (score 0):

You said that first you need to check whether `value` is null or not and then also check whether the value is empty or not,

You can do the following

```
if (obj.getMoney() != null && obj.getMoney().getValue() != null && !obj.getMoney().getValue().isEmpty()) {
      // rest of the code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating your obj, gives a new. The form of validation is correct, the problem is in the obj that was not initialized. (I believe)